# $\lim_{y \to 0^+} (g(x+iy)-g(x-iy))$, where the analytic function $g$ is $g(z) = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Let $g(z) = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t-z}$, analytic on $O=
>  \mathbb{C}-[0,1]$. Find $\lim_{y \to 0^+} (g(x+iy)-g(x-iy))$, where $x
>  \in (0,1)$.

I think I could explore the fact that $g(z)-g(\bar{z}) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{t}} - \frac{1}{1-\frac{\bar{z}}{t}}) dt$, but it it unclear. Is anyone could help me at this point?

Comment: $g(z) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_\epsilon^{1-\epsilon} \frac{dt}{t-z}$. what is the derivative of $\log(t-z)$ ? (and be careful with the branch of the logarithm, that's what the $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}$ is useful for)

Comment: Where did you get the factor of $\frac{1}{t}$ from?

Comment: @user1952009 I would like to know your solution with your hint to compare with the answer of Friedrich Philipp. Could you display an answer? It is curious how could pass of $\log$ to $\arctan$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have calculated correctly, then
$$
g(x+iy)-g(x-iy) = -2i\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1-x}{y}\right) - \arctan\left(-\frac x y\right)\right).
$$
Now, let $y\to 0+$ and take care of $x$.

EDIT: In your original post, you have a $\frac 1 t$ too much in the integral. For your understanding, here is my calculation:
\begin{align*}
g(x+iy)-g(x-iy)
&= \int_0^1\left(\frac 1 {(t-x)+iy} - \frac 1 {(t-x)-iy}\right)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{(t-x)-iy - ((t-x)+iy)}{(t-x)^2 + y^2}\,dt\\
&= -2iy\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(t-x)^2 + y^2}\,dt.
\end{align*}
Now, substitute $s = (t-x)/y$. Then $ds/dt = 1/y$ and
\begin{align*}
g(x+iy)-g(x-iy)
&= -2i\int_{-x/y}^{(1-x)/y} \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}\,ds.
\end{align*}